# How can to install multiple versions of javascript library using nuget?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I want to install multiple versions of bootstrap on my project but when I do so using package manager console, nuget is just updating it.

Is it possible to install multiple versions of javascript library at all using nuget?

Answer (score 1):

Not into the same project. A project will have only one version of a NuGet package.